# How to display error validation on specific modal for updating data with laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I try to update the data of products on modal bootstrap, but every product has its own update form.

But error validation displays on all modals update of others products (same fields).

Can I use named message bags for this problem?

I have one form of updating for all products.

My view:

```
@foreach($prdCatg as $prd)

        <div id="modifier" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" >

            <div class=" modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">

                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title titre">Modifier le produit</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                    </div>

                    
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('com.produit.update') }}" enctype = "multipart/form-data">

                        @csrf
                        @method('PATCH')
                            
                        <div class="modal-body row justify-content-center">

                        <input type="hidden" id="id_prd" name="id_produit" value="">

                            <div class="col-lg-6">

                                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                    <label for="Nom"  class="col-form-label">Nom du produit :</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="Nom" id="nom" class="shadow form-control @error ('Nom') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('Nom') }}">
                                    @error('Nom')
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            {{$errors->first('Nom')}}
                                        </div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                    <label class="col-form-label" for="Catégorie">Le client :</label>
                                    <select name="Client" id="clt" class="shadow custom-select @error ('Client') is-invalid @enderror" style="color:#787878;">
                                        
                                        @foreach($clts as $clt)
                                            <option value="{{$clt->id_soc}}" {{$prd->soc_id == $clt->id_soc ? 'selected' : ''}}> {{$clt->nom_soc}} </option>
                                        @endforeach

                                    </select>

                                    @error('Client')
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            {{$errors->first('Client')}}
                                        </div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                    <label class="col-form-label" for="Catégorie">La catégorie :</label>
                                    <select name="Catégorie" id="catg" class="shadow custom-select @error ('Catégorie') is-invalid @enderror" style="color:#787878;">
                                    
                                        @foreach($catgs as $catg)
                                            <option value="{{ $catg->id_catg }}" {{$prd->catg_id == $catg->id_catg ? 'selected' : ''}}> {{ $catg->nom_catg }} </option>                                        
                                        @endforeach
    
                                    </select>
                                    
                                    @error('Catégorie')
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            {{$errors->first('Catégorie')}}
                                        </div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-6">

                                
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                    <label for="Prix"  class="col-form-label">Prix unitaire :</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="Prix" id="prix" class="shadow form-control @error ('Prix') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('Prix')}}">
                                    @error('Prix')
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{$errors->first('Prix')}}
                                        </div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                    <label for="Description" class="col-form-label">Description :</label>
                                    <textarea type="text" name="Description" id="descp" class="shadow form-control @error ('Description') is-invalid @enderror" rows="2" value="{{ old('Description')}}">
                                    </textarea>
                                    @error('Description')
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            {{$errors->first('Description')}}
                                        </div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">   
                                    <label for="Logo"  class="col-form-label">Logo du produit :</label>         
                                    <div class="custom-file shadow">
                                        <input type="file" id="logo" name="Logo" class="custom-file-input @error ('Logo') is-invalid @enderror">
                                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="lm" style="color:#787878">Votre fichier.</label>
                                        <small>Formats acceptés : .jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.png</small>
                                        <small> Tailles acceptées : hauteur_max:200px, largeur_max:200px </small>
                                        @error('Logo')
                                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                {{$errors->first('Logo')}}
                                            </div>
                                        @enderror 
                                    </div>            
                                </div>
                            </div>         

                            <div class="form-group row justify-content-center col-lg-10" style="margin-top:20px;">
                                <div class="">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Modifier
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    @endforeach
```

javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#modifier').on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var prd_id = button.data('prdid')
        var nom = button.data('prdnom')
        var clt = button.data('prdclt')
        var catg = button.data('prdcatg')
        var prix = button.data('prdprix')
        var descp = button.data('prddescp')

        var modal = $(this)

        modal.find('.modal-body #id_prd').val(prd_id);
        modal.find('.modal-body #nom').val(nom);
        modal.find('.modal-body #clt').val(clt);
        modal.find('.modal-body #catg').val(catg);
        modal.find('.modal-body #prix').val(prix);
        modal.find('.modal-body #descp').val(descp);
    })
</script>  

 @if (count($errors) > 0)
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#modifier').modal('show');
    });
</script>

@endif
```

controller :

```
 public function update(Request $request)
{
    
    $id_prd = $request->input('id_produit');

    request()->validate([
        
        'Nom'=>'required',
        'Client' => 'required',
        'Catégorie' => 'required',
        'Prix' => 'required|integer|not_in:0',
        'Description' => 'required|between:20,300',
        'Logo' => 'sometimes|image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|dimensions:max_heigh=200,max_width=200',

    ]);

    $produit = Produit::find($id_prd);

    if(request()->has('Logo')){
    
        $upload_logo = request()->file('Logo');
        $logo_name = request('Nom').'.'. $upload_logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $logo_path = public_path('/img/produit/');
        $upload_logo->move($logo_path, $logo_name);


        $produit ->nom_prd = $request->get('Nom');
        $produit ->soc_id = $request->get('Client');
        $produit ->soc_id = $request->get('Catégorie');
        $produit ->prix_prd = $request->get('Prix');
        $produit ->descp_prd = $request->get('Description');
        $produit ->logo_prd = '/img/produit/'.$logo_name;

        $produit->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Le produit a été mis à jour, merci !');
    }

    $produit ->nom_prd = $request->get('Nom');
    $produit ->soc_id = $request->get('Client');
    $produit ->soc_id = $request->get('Catégorie');
    $produit ->prix_prd = $request->get('Prix');
    $produit ->descp_prd = $request->get('Description');

    $produit->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Le produit a été mis à jour, merci !');
}

public function destroy(Request $request){

    $prd_id = $request->input('id_produit');
    $prd = Produit::where('id_prd',$prd_id);
    $prd -> delete();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Le produit a été supprimé.');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use one `<form>` and use indexed input names. If I'm correct you can use `attribute.x` (like `Client.8`) to get the error message.

```
<form>
  @csrf

  @foreach ($prdCatg as $prd)
    <input name="Client[{{ $prd->id }}]" value="{{ $prd->value }}">

    @error('Client.' . $prd->id)
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {{ $message }} <!-- you can use this in L7 or you can still use $errors->first('Client.' . $prd->id) -->
      </div>
    @enderror
  @endforeach
</form>
```

This would at least solve one problem. But make sure you don't have too much models loaded, because of performance ;)

Comment: Thank's for your suggestions, now please one thing. When i submit,  if There is errors validations, the error appear but the old values disapear,  even using old('') think on Views. I think the js code is the problem. Have you an idea how i can resolve this ???